# unable to set innerHeight using Html Service

Tags: google-apps-script

This is a toy page with a script that assigns innerHeight to fill the whole screen, no more, no less.

```
<html><body>
<div style="height:30px;">header<div>
<div id="box" style="border:3px solid red;"></div>
<script>document.getElementById("box").style.height=window.innerHeight-36;</script>
</body></html>
```

If I load such a page from the following script:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myPage').evaluate();
}
```

the javascript code line doesn't work; that is, the setting of innerHeight has no effect. Is there any workaround I can use to make the second div filling the whole height of the screen, no more and no less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this now. At least that I know of. There's an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1505) opened in Caja issue tracker regarding this. You might want to *star* it to keep track of updates.

Answer (score 0):

Nope sorry. The HTML service does not seem to accept the JavaScript window method.